# Where to create all database-relative functions in Symfony?

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter, symfony, service, repository

I am currently moving a project from a CodeIgniter + MySQL architecture to a Symfony + MongoDB architecture.

I used to have a model for each of my entities. In this model I had some functions to create / insert / get / delete / update my entities. Since these functions were in the model, I was able to use them in various controller.

I would like to do the exact same thing with my new architecture (Symfony2 + MySQL).

What is the best way to accomplish that ? Create a Repository ? Create a Service ?

Answer (score 2):

I sugget you to create `Manager` classes where you will store all the business logic. You could also use doctrine `Repository` classes, but you cannot easily inject services in them.